# Index process in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2, index

I am new to Magento. I build a new site (currently is live in Joomla and the reason that I change that my products will be more than 500.000. now is at 350.000 in Joomla) I am in Magento in localhost. I have imported 35.000 products so far and I tried to index. The problem is that it stucks on index.

> info@LAPTOP-5SEJ1RGM c:\xampp\htdocs\gigaparts

```
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00<br>
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00<br>
```

***This is the result after 9 hours and this is what I see on admin.***

```
    Design Config Grid  Rebuild design config grid index    Update on Save  Ready Sep 5, 2019, 12:12:11 AM

    Customer Grid   Rebuild Customer grid index     Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 12:12:12 AM

    Category Products   Indexed category/products association   Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 1:58:30 AM

    Product Categories  Indexed product/categories association  Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 1:58:30 AM

    Catalog Rule Product    Indexed rule/product association    Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 8:57:07 AM

    Product EAV     Index<br> product EAV   Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 8:57:20 AM

    Stock   Index stock     Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 8:57:24 AM

    Inventory   Inventory index (MSI)   Update on Save  Ready   Sep 5, 2019, 8:57:24 AM

    Catalog Product Rule    Indexed product/rule association    Update on Save  Ready   Sep 4, 2019, 2:02:49 PM

    Product Price   Index product prices    Update on Save  Processing  Sep 5, 2019, 8:57:24 AM

    Catalog Search  Rebuild Catalog product fulltext search index   Update on Save  Reindex required    Sep 4, 2019, 4:32:51 PM
```

***Obviously something is wrong. Does it need 9 hours for 35.000? What if I reach 500.000?***

*Please help...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Magento Issue Of **Product Flat Data index**

[Check This Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23462)

And Also Relese Patch For This issue

[Patch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23462#issuecomment-512904404)

Downloaded `flat_composer.patch.txt` File Paste On Your Magento Root Directory

> **Ex:- var/www/html/magento232**

**And Execute This Command `patch -p1 < flat_composer.patch.txt`**

**File :-**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Table\BuilderInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

/**
 * Class TableBuilder
 */
class TableBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Flat\Indexer
     */
    protected $_productIndexerHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $_connection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool
     */
    protected $metadataPool;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resource;

    /**
     * @var BuilderInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $tableBuilderFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Flat\Indexer $productIndexerHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param BuilderInterfaceFactory|null $tableBuilderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Flat\Indexer $productIndexerHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        BuilderInterfaceFactory $tableBuilderFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->_productIndexerHelper = $productIndexerHelper;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $this->tableBuilderFactory = $tableBuilderFactory ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(BuilderInterfaceFactory::class);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare temporary tables only for first call of reindex all
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param array $changedIds
     * @param string $valueFieldSuffix
     * @return void
     */
    public function build($storeId, $changedIds, $valueFieldSuffix)
    {
        $entityTableName = $this->_productIndexerHelper->getTable('catalog_product_entity');
        $attributes = $this->_productIndexerHelper->getAttributes();
        $eavAttributes = $this->_productIndexerHelper->getTablesStructure($attributes);
        $entityTableColumns = $eavAttributes[$entityTableName];
        $linkField = $this->getMetadataPool()
            ->getMetadata(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class)
            ->getLinkField();

        $temporaryEavAttributes = $eavAttributes;

        //add status global value to the base table
        /* @var $status \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute */
        $status = $this->_productIndexerHelper->getAttribute('status');
        $temporaryEavAttributes[$status->getBackendTable()]['status'] = $status;
        //Create list of temporary tables based on available attributes attributes
        $valueTables = [];
        foreach ($temporaryEavAttributes as $tableName => $columns) {
            $valueTables = array_merge(
                $valueTables,
                $this->_createTemporaryTable($this->_getTemporaryTableName($tableName), $columns, $valueFieldSuffix)
            );
        }

        //Fill "base" table which contains all available products
        $this->_fillTemporaryEntityTable($entityTableName, $entityTableColumns, $changedIds);

        //Add primary key to "base" temporary table for increase speed of joins in future
        $this->_addPrimaryKeyToTable($this->_getTemporaryTableName($entityTableName));
        unset($temporaryEavAttributes[$entityTableName]);

        foreach ($temporaryEavAttributes as $tableName => $columns) {
            $temporaryTableName = $this->_getTemporaryTableName($tableName);

            //Add primary key to temporary table for increase speed of joins in future
            $this->_addPrimaryKeyToTable($temporaryTableName, $linkField);

            //Create temporary table for composite attributes
            if (isset($valueTables[$temporaryTableName . $valueFieldSuffix])) {
                $this->_addPrimaryKeyToTable($temporaryTableName . $valueFieldSuffix, $linkField);
            }

            //Fill temporary tables with attributes grouped by it type
            $this->_fillTemporaryTable($tableName, $columns, $changedIds, $valueFieldSuffix, $storeId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create empty temporary table with given columns list
     *
     * @param string $tableName Table name
     * @param array $columns array('columnName' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute, ...)
     * @param string $valueFieldSuffix
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _createTemporaryTable($tableName, array $columns, $valueFieldSuffix)
    {
        $valueTables = [];
        if (!empty($columns)) {
            $valueTableName = $tableName . $valueFieldSuffix;
            $temporaryTableBuilder = $this->tableBuilderFactory->create(
                [
                    'connection' => $this->_connection,
                    'tableName' => $tableName
                ]
            );
            $valueTemporaryTableBuilder = $this->tableBuilderFactory->create(
                [
                    'connection' => $this->_connection,
                    'tableName' => $valueTableName
                ]
            );
            $flatColumns = $this->_productIndexerHelper->getFlatColumns();

            $temporaryTableBuilder->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['unsigned'=>true]
            );

            $temporaryTableBuilder->addColumn('type_id', \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT);

            $temporaryTableBuilder->addColumn('attribute_set_id', \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER);

            $valueTemporaryTableBuilder->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['unsigned'=>true]
            );

            /** @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute */
            foreach ($columns as $columnName => $attribute) {
                $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                if (isset($flatColumns[$attributeCode])) {
                    $column = $flatColumns[$attributeCode];
                } else {
                    $column = $attribute->_getFlatColumnsDdlDefinition();
                    $column = $column[$attributeCode];
                }

                $temporaryTableBuilder->addColumn(
                    $columnName,
                    $column['type'],
                    isset($column['length']) ? $column['length'] : null
                );

                $columnValueName = $attributeCode . $valueFieldSuffix;
                if (isset($flatColumns[$columnValueName])) {
                    $columnValue = $flatColumns[$columnValueName];
                    $valueTemporaryTableBuilder->addColumn(
                        $columnValueName,
                        $columnValue['type'],
                        isset($columnValue['length']) ? $columnValue['length'] : null
                    );
                }
            }
            $this->_connection->dropTemporaryTable($tableName);
            $this->_connection->createTemporaryTable($temporaryTableBuilder->getTable());

            if (count($valueTemporaryTableBuilder->getTable()->getColumns()) > 1) {
                $this->_connection->dropTemporaryTable($valueTableName);
                $this->_connection->createTemporaryTable($valueTemporaryTableBuilder->getTable());
                $valueTables[$valueTableName] = $valueTableName;
            }
        }
        return $valueTables;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve temporary table name by regular table name
     *
     * @param string $tableName
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getTemporaryTableName($tableName)
    {
        return sprintf('%s_tmp_indexer', $tableName);
    }

    /**
     * Fill temporary entity table
     *
     * @param string $tableName
     * @param array $columns
     * @param array $changedIds
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function _fillTemporaryEntityTable($tableName, array $columns, array $changedIds = [])
    {
        if (!empty($columns)) {
            $select = $this->_connection->select();
            $temporaryEntityTable = $this->_getTemporaryTableName($tableName);
            $metadata = $this->getMetadataPool()->getMetadata(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
            $idsColumns = array_unique([$metadata->getLinkField(), 'entity_id', 'type_id', 'attribute_set_id']);

            $columns = array_merge($idsColumns, array_keys($columns));

            $select->from(['e' => $tableName], $columns);
            $onDuplicate = false;
            if (!empty($changedIds)) {
                $select->where($this->_connection->quoteInto('e.entity_id IN (?)', $changedIds));
                $onDuplicate = true;
            }
            $sql = $select->insertFromSelect($temporaryEntityTable, $columns, $onDuplicate);
            $this->_connection->query($sql);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add primary key to table by it name
     *
     * @param string $tableName
     * @param string $columnName
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _addPrimaryKeyToTable($tableName, $columnName = 'entity_id')
    {
        $this->_connection->addIndex(
            $tableName,
            'entity_id',
            [$columnName],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_PRIMARY
        );
    }

    /**
     * Fill temporary table by data from products EAV attributes by type
     *
     * @param string $tableName
     * @param array $tableColumns
     * @param array $changedIds
     * @param string $valueFieldSuffix
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function _fillTemporaryTable(
        $tableName,
        array $tableColumns,
        array $changedIds,
        $valueFieldSuffix,
        $storeId
    ) {
        $metadata = $this->getMetadataPool()->getMetadata(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
        if (!empty($tableColumns)) {
            $columnsChunks = array_chunk(
                $tableColumns,
                Action\Indexer::ATTRIBUTES_CHUNK_SIZE / 2,
                true
            );
            foreach ($columnsChunks as $columnsList) {
                $select = $this->_connection->select();
                $selectValue = $this->_connection->select();
                $entityTableName = $this->_getTemporaryTableName(
                    $this->_productIndexerHelper->getTable('catalog_product_entity')
                );
                $temporaryTableName = $this->_getTemporaryTableName($tableName);
                $temporaryValueTableName = $temporaryTableName . $valueFieldSuffix;
                $keyColumn = array_unique([$metadata->getLinkField(), 'entity_id']);
                $columns = array_merge($keyColumn, array_keys($columnsList));
                $valueColumns = $keyColumn;
                $flatColumns = $this->_productIndexerHelper->getFlatColumns();
                $iterationNum = 1;

                $select->from(['et' => $entityTableName], $keyColumn)
                    ->join(
                        ['e' => $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity')],
                        'e.entity_id = et.entity_id',
                        []
                    );

                $selectValue->from(['e' => $temporaryTableName], $keyColumn);

                /** @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute */
                foreach ($columnsList as $columnName => $attribute) {
                    $countTableName = 't' . ($iterationNum++);
                    $joinCondition = 'e.%3$s = %1$s.%3$s AND %1$s.attribute_id = %2$d AND %1$s.store_id = %4$d';
                    $select->joinLeft(
                        [$countTableName => $tableName],
                        sprintf(
                            $joinCondition,
                            $countTableName,
                            $attribute->getId(),
                            $metadata->getLinkField(),
                            Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
                        ),
                        []
                    )->joinLeft(
                        ['s' . $countTableName => $tableName],
                        sprintf(
                            $joinCondition,
                            's' . $countTableName,
                            $attribute->getId(),
                            $metadata->getLinkField(),
                            $storeId
                        ),
                        []
                    );

                    $columnValue = $this->_connection->getIfNullSql(
                        's' . $countTableName . '.value',
                        $countTableName . '.value'
                    );

                    $select->columns([$columnName => $columnValue]);

                    if ($attribute->getFlatUpdateSelect($storeId) instanceof \Magento\Framework\DB\Select) {
                        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                        $columnValueName = $attributeCode . $valueFieldSuffix;
                        if (isset($flatColumns[$columnValueName])) {
                            $valueJoinCondition = 'e.%1$s = %2$s.option_id AND %2$s.store_id = %3$d';
                            $selectValue->joinLeft(
                                [
                                    $countTableName => $this->_productIndexerHelper->getTable(
                                        'eav_attribute_option_value'
                                    ),
                                ],
                                sprintf(
                                    $valueJoinCondition,
                                    $attributeCode,
                                    $countTableName,
                                    Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
                                ),
                                []
                            );
                            $selectValue->joinLeft(
                                [
                                    's' . $countTableName => $this->_productIndexerHelper->getTable(
                                        'eav_attribute_option_value'
                                    ),
                                ],
                                sprintf(
                                    $valueJoinCondition,
                                    $attributeCode,
                                    's' . $countTableName,
                                    $storeId
                                ),
                                []
                            );

                            $columnValue = $this->_connection->getIfNullSql(
                                's' . $countTableName . '.value',
                                $countTableName . '.value'
                            );

                            $selectValue->columns([$columnValueName => $columnValue]);
                            $valueColumns[] = $columnValueName;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($changedIds)) {
                    $select->where($this->_connection->quoteInto('e.entity_id IN (?)', $changedIds));
                }

                $sql = $select->insertFromSelect($temporaryTableName, $columns, true);
                $this->_connection->query($sql);

                if (count($valueColumns) > 1) {
                    if (!empty($changedIds)) {
                        $selectValue->where($this->_connection->quoteInto('e.entity_id IN (?)', $changedIds));
                    }
                    $sql = $selectValue->insertFromSelect($temporaryValueTableName, $valueColumns, true);
                    $this->_connection->query($sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Metadata Pool
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool
     * @deprecated 101.1.0
     */
    private function getMetadataPool()
    {
        if (null === $this->metadataPool) {
            $this->metadataPool = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool::class);
        }
        return $this->metadataPool;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this but i got $ git apply flat.patch.txt
error: app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/TableBuilder.php: No such file or directory

should i change the path in this file or what? My location for TableBuilder.php file is C:\xampp\htdocs\gigaparts\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat

Comment: let me check...

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: info@LAPTOP-5SEJ1RGM MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/gigaparts
$ patch -p1 < flat_composer.patch.txt
patching file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/TableBuilder.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/TableBuilder.php.rej
Please advise

Comment: 1st Revert TableBuilder.php this file then after apply  Patch.

Comment: https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/TableBuilder.php file link

Comment: I copied new content to TableBuilder.php. I runned patch -p1 < flat_composer.patch.txt. Result is info@LAPTOP-5SEJ1RGM MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/gigaparts
$ patch -p1 < flat_composer.patch.txt
patching file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/TableBuilder.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 6.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 234 (offset -42 lines).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 305.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 368.
3 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/TableBuilder.php.rej

Comment: magento version ??

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.2

Comment: im attach TableBuilder File Just Copy And Paste This File And Try

Comment: in this file im already apply patch..

Comment: Did that and started index. I will provide more info later on.

Comment: reset the indexing process and try to reindex again

Comment: Done that 1st but its already 5 minutes indexing Category Products. 20.000 products i have so far

Comment: It is 20 minutes and still indexing Category Products. Shouldnt that be fixed with this patch?

Comment: yes issue solved

Comment: Unfortunatelly its not yet solved. Its 55 minutes and its stuck again in Category Products. Please advise
# php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Comment: It seems that this matter is now resolved since it moved to Rebuild Catalog product fulltext search index . It took Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 01:01:12 but it went on. Are these times acceptable for 20k products? (I am asking to verify that all are ok now.) Also please advise how to upvote and approve answer for helpfull other user

Comment: Thank you for your support. Adding this code as you instructed me has resolved the problem. Thank you very much for your excellent assist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98330/discussion-on-answer-by-rk-rathod-index-process-in-magento-2-3-2).